# Gost Apahche2 Processes Can Not Be Removed

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, apache2, nginx

I have a 20.04 server installation. Once I installed apache2 http server and switch to nginx..

Before to do that I run the following command to clean uninstall

`sudo apt-get remove --purge --autoremove apache2`

Apache2 gets removed, everything was removed. But I realized that when I ran `ps aux --sort=-%mem`. There are still apache2 processes and I don't know how to turn them off.

Is there any way to kill them permanently or am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you forgot to STOP Apache before removing the software ? Have you tried to reboot ?

Comment: You can nuke the processes with `sudo kill 09 $(which apache2)` but you might want to figure out instead why you didn't *stop* it from running before removing it.  You have to stop the process before removing it for it to go away.  Or reboot your box

Comment: @SorenA Yes I always stop the services before remove them.

Comment: @ThomasWard . I kill them and reboot them but they still keep running